# Round number after 0,1

Tags: vba, excel, rounding

As you know,  number rounds bigger one after 0,5 , but I want that number rounds bigger one after 0.1 . Can I do it ?

Where I will use it is ;

I will take input from user and ı will copy them ten by ten other worksheet. For example, ıf the user input's is 11, then I have to open 2 sheets .

Comment: Lot of things to  improve  on your question : remove the `vb.net` tag as this seems to be `excel-vba`. Show your numbers. You should solve this by coding a formula or a vba function and the precision after the decimal point of your numbers is an important parameter to know. Do you have only numbers alike `0.5` and `0.1` or can you have numbers alike `0.55214` or `4587.256487952487552` ?

Comment: I have numbers 0.1 , 0.2,0.3, 0.4 , 0,5 ,06 0.7,0,8,0.9

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the existing behavior of the `ROUND()` function by adding a value to it like:

```
ROUND(x + 0,4, 2) '2 decimal places, 0.4 added as a bias
```

In this way, if x were 5,1, you'd really be rounding 5,1 + 0,4 or 5,5, and then the normal behavior of the function would work for you.  Adding a bias in this way lets you control rounding (up) behavior easily.